# enum static variable reference between java

Tags: java, junit, enums, architecture, static

I have three java files I'm working with and using Junit.

The test class is where I'm getting my error in regard to an enum that is in the main class.

**EDIT**

I found out that the this was working as is.  Just not in a larger scale implementation.

Goods.java

```
class Good {
    private static StaticTest.THESES name;
    static void setStatusName(StaticTest.THESES status) {
       name = status;
    }
    static StaticTest.THESES getStatusName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Test.class

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class Tests {

     @Test 
     public void test() {
        Good good = new Good();
        good.setStatusName(Library.STATUSES.HIM);
        String actual = good.getStatusName().toString();

         String expected = Library.STATUSES.HIM.toString();
         assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Tests runningTest = new Tests();
        runningTest.test();
    }
}

class Library {
    public static enum STATUSES {
        YOU, ME, HER, HIM, THEM, US
    }
}
```

can you tell me what I can't find any values from my products class?

Comment: `private Library.STATUSES status;` is not `static`. This code only compiles because of a quirk - `status = status` assigns the value to _itself_.

Comment: Please follow the Java naming conventions.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't think `getStatus()` compiles.

Comment: The other point worth mentioning: your "production code" (class Good) should absolutely **not** depend on anything in your "test code". Test code depends on production code, but not vice versa!

Comment: @shmosel i reckon it should; but I'm lazy and haven't tried. Also, I haven't used a method without `final` arguments in about 3 years so I might well be wrong...

Comment: @BoristheSpider I was referring to the second method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a better grasp of what it means to declare something `static`. I think each `Good` will need to have its own status right - so you are on the right track by not declaring your `private status` as `static`. Your problem (as Boris pointed out) is that you are trying to mutate the instance variable `status` by using `static` (class level) methods.

I think you will want to use something like the below to start you off.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Good good = new Good();
        good.setStatus(Library.STATUS.SALE);
        System.out.println("Good's status: " + good.getStatus());
    }

}

class Good {

    private Library.STATUS status;

    public void setStatus(Library.STATUS status) {
       this.status = status;
    }
    public Library.STATUS getStatus() {
       return status;
    }
}

class Library {

    public enum STATUS { 
          SALE, NOSALEITEM, ITEMOOS, SHIPPING, ONORDER, INSTOCK
     }
}
```