# enum test junit arraylist being overwritten reinstantiating not working

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a post that describes the class structure a
[enum static variable reference between java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134283/enum-static-variable-reference-between-java?noredirect=1#comment65615924_39134283) but as I began finishing up testing I'm running into a trivial error where I create the ArrayList but the debug statement show me that the Class Object is either the new list item created or the constructor default values.

```
@Test
public GoodsTest()        
    clearProductMaps();
    Goods item = new Goods();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JULY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 21);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
    date = calendar.getTime();
    item.setName("FirstItem_A");
    item.setPrice(4.10);
    item.setStatus(Library.STATUSES.US);
    item.setDate(date);

    actualGoods.add(0,item);
    item = new Goods();
    item.setProductName("FirstItem_A");
    item.setPrice(3.70);
    item.setStatus(Library.STATUSES.ME);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.AUGUST);
    date = calendar.getTime();
    item.setDate(date);

    actualGoods.add(item);
    System.out.println("debug " + actualGoods.get(0).getStatus());
}
```

My clearProductMaps just mandates the List is empty for the test.

The print statement is : debug ME
when I am expected the statement to be : debug US

Comment: Sorry, but no idea what you are asking. No idea what your test is supposed to do ("yes, GoodsTest", but what specifically?) Pointing to one problem with your code: bad naming. Variable names start lower case, and "Item" - what should that be? You got "goodsItem" there, too. And calendear and date. And only posting the test method without the variable declarations doesn't help. Please note: nothing about your code is **trivial**. All of it is quite **confusing**. Then: if output is confusing you; then please please: provide that output here. We are not wizards!

Comment: How would we know what you see? How would we know the difference between actualGoods(0) and actualGoods(1); given the fact that you are showing just parts of your code. Seriously: you should try to step back and first get the **confusion** out of the things you are doing. Focus on small aspects, and work on them one by one.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @RC Thanks for that.

Comment: `Item = new Goods();` And what is happening inside `clearProductMaps()`

Comment: @Ambrish made an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently `setStatus` of both different `Good`s seem to write to the same field. So this field is `static`. Static fields are fields of the class object Good.

As you spoke of enum, every enum constant is a static global singleton too.

```
enum Status {
    SLEEPY,
    ENERGETIC;

    public int coffee;
}
```

Now the two objects each have a single `coffee`. Assigning it would be valid for either all SLEEPY or ENERGETIC occurrences. Such a confusion seems to be the case with Library.STATUSES.ME/US.